# How to repeat observation in a variety range?

Tags: date, for-loop, stata

I want to repeat `drop` variable for next `date` in each `name`.

Consider the following data frame:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str4 name long date str8 time float drop
"A" 17659 "11:32:41" 1
"A" 17659 "12:32:41" 1
"A" 17659 "13:32:41" 1
"A" 17660 "11:32:41" .
"A" 17660 "12:32:41" .
"A" 17660 "13:32:41" .
"A" 17660 "14:32:41" .
"B" 17659 "11:32:41" .
"B" 17659 "12:32:41" .
"B" 17659 "13:32:41" .
"B" 17659 "14:32:41" .
"B" 17660 "11:32:41" 1
"B" 17660 "12:32:41" 1
"B" 17661 "11:32:41" 1
"B" 17661 "12:32:41" 1
"C" 17659 "11:32:41" 1
"C" 17659 "12:32:41" 1
"C" 17660 "11:32:41" .
"C" 17660 "12:32:41" .
"C" 17660 "13:32:41" .
"C" 17661 "11:32:41" .
"C" 17661 "12:32:41" .
"C" 17661 "13:32:41" .
"C" 17661 "14:32:41" .
end
format %d date
```

So the result is:

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| name |   date    |   time   | drop  |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| A    | 07may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 07may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 07may2008 | 13:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 08may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 08may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 08may2008 | 13:32:41 |     1 |
| A    | 08may2008 | 14:32:41 |     1 |
| B    | 07may2008 | 11:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 12:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 13:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 14:32:41 |       |
| B    | 08may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| B    | 08may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| B    | 09may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| B    | 09may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 07may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 07may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 08may2008 | 11:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 08may2008 | 12:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 08may2008 | 13:32:41 |     1 |
| C    | 09may2008 | 11:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 12:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 13:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 14:32:41 |       |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

Finaly if we use `drop if drop == 1` the result is:

```
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| name |   date    |   time   | drop  |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
| B    | 07may2008 | 11:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 12:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 13:32:41 |       |
| B    | 07may2008 | 14:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 11:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 12:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 13:32:41 |       |
| C    | 09may2008 | 14:32:41 |       |
+------+-----------+----------+-------+
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some of your code.

Comment: Maybe I can use `gen drop2 = drop[_n-1]` to make a new observation equals 1 for next date and then add it to `drop` variable for that `date`.

Comment: You are basically asking for a solution to deal with the duplicate entries from your previous post. So do you simply want to drop all duplicates after the next date?

Comment: No. I just want to delete observations which the `drop` value is equal 1.

Comment: Well, in that case what's wrong with `replace name = . if drop == 1`?

Comment: Please consider the procedure which is shown above. I have a `drop` variable and I want to add value 1 to the next `date` if `drop == 1`, the final result is the last table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168978/discussion-between-amin-karimi-and-pearly-spencer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gen a=0
replace a=1 if(drop[_n]==1 & drop[_n+1]==. & name[_n]==name[_n+1] & _n < _N)
replace a=1 if(drop[_n]==. & drop[_n-1]==1 & name[_n]==name[_n-1] & _n < _N)
bysort name date: egen b=max(a)
sort name date

drop if b==1
drop if drop ==1
drop drop a b
```

EDIT Nick Cox

```
gen a = drop==1 & drop[_n+1]==. & name==name[_n+1] & _n < _N
replace a=1 if drop==. & drop[_n-1]==1 & name==name[_n-1] & _n < _N
bysort name date (a): gen b = a[_N] 

drop if b==1 | drop ==1
drop drop a b
```

Comment: +1 from me for the creative use of `egen`. Also, using `replace` without a `for` loop is a nice touch and will be faster in larger datasets.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of shortening your code and showing how you can avoid `egen`. The condition `_n < _N` is superfluous in the first statement as `name[_N] == name[_N+1]` is impossible unless `name[_N]` is missing.